# telethon, async

Tags: python, asyncio, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time
api_id = 123123
api_hash = '123123123'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('https://t.me/chat')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    a = event.message.to_dict()
    b = a['message'].lower()
    
async def tme():
    if time.time()%10 == 0:
        print(time.time())
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(tme())     

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Здравствуйте, как сделать так, чтобы ф-ция tme работала постоянно, а не вызывалась 1 раз. Первая программа с async. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Я конечно с telethon не работал, но в теоре вот так должно работать..

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time
api_id = 123123
api_hash = '123123123'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('https://t.me/chat')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    a = event.message.to_dict()
    b = a['message'].lower()
    
async def tme():
    if time.time()%10 == 0:
        print(time.time())
with client:
    while True:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(tme())     

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Если первый вариант не будет работать то попробуйте этот:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time
api_id = 123123
api_hash = '123123123'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('https://t.me/chat')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    a = event.message.to_dict()
    b = a['message'].lower()
    
async def tme():
    if time.time()%10 == 0:
        print(time.time())
with client:
    while True:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(tme())     
        client.start()
        client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: первый вариант действительно работает, только нужно if int(time.time())%10 == 0: но к сожалению он выводит слишком много сообщений, за 1 включение.

Comment: Ну тогда можно вместо time, использовать datatime!: 
```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(f"{now.hour}:{now.minute}:{now.second}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).